# How to fix a "Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to two 'NSNumber' operands" error

Tags: swift

I am working on some Swift code at a new job, and I am receiving an error on a line that compares two NSNumbers.  The line is:

```
if let endOffset = offsets.endOffset where clip.sessionOffset > offsets.startOffset
```

The error is:

Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to two 'NSNumber' operands"

I'm using Xcode 7.1, and the code compiles successfully on a coworker's computer.  My expectation is that Swift should automatically unbox the NSNumbers, and the line should compile.

Comment: The error says `<` but the code has `>`?

Comment: Sorry, I pulled the error from a different line by mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import Foundation    
let a: NSNumber = 1
let b: NSNumber = 2
let c = a

a.compare(b) == .orderedAscending  // true
b.compare(a) == .orderedDescending // true
a.compare(c) == .orderedSame       // true
```

Comment: Any thoughts as to why the code compiles on my co-worker's computer, but not on mine?

Comment: @CarlSmith that pretty much says nothing, there's a million different possible reasons.

Comment: you can define the operator for that, maybe it is done somewhere  in the source on your co-workers computer ... maybe sessionOffset, startOffset are not NSNumbers ...

Comment: Just found an extension for NSNumber in SwiftyJSON.swift that provides functions that all the comparison operators.  Trying to figure out why those functions are not being picked up by the compiler.